Applying Layouts, and Middlwares to Parent and Child Routes Nuxt 3
I'm building my first nuxt3 app and I'm trying to add auth to a specific route and its children. Do I need to add the fallowing piece of code in every child to have the auth middleware?
definePageMeta({
    layout: "default",
    name: "become-a-pro",
    middleware: "auth",
});

There's a way to add it only in the parent page?
my folder/file structure is very simple as smt like this and I would like to set all the children to have the auth middleware without adding it to every each one of them:
----- parent
     |--- children 1
          |--- children 1a
          |--- children 1b
     |--- children 2
          |--- children 2a
          |--- children 2b
     |--- children 3
          |--- children 3a
          |--- children 3b



Yes, there is a way to add Middlewares and Layouts.
Pages structure Example:
--pages
   |--index.vue
   |--parent.vue // File     
   |--parent // Folder
      |--index.vue // Parent Main page
      |--child1.vue
      |--child2.vue      

In your ~/pages/parent.vue
In this page, you need to wrap the NuxtPage with NuxtLayout component. In the Nuxtlayout component, it has a prop called name. The name should match the name of the file available in the layouts folder.
You can also use definePageMeta and call the middleware. Since this is a parent route, the middleware will apply on the available children routes.


<script lang="ts" setup>
definePageMeta({
  middleware: ['aut']
})
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout name="default">
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>



Or
~/pages/parent.vue


<script lang="ts" setup>
definePageMeta({
  middleware: ['aut'],
  layout: 'admin'
})
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>



Both options work the same.
~app.vue


<script setup>

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>



Hope that helps!

All of your children routes (children 1, 1a, 1b, 2, etc.) inherit the auth middleware from parent.vue. No further definePageMeta is needed in the children.
